# Detect when a user selects checkmark in v-data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

Is there an event that gets emitted when a user checks/unchecks a box in a v-data-table?  If not, is there an appropriate place I should add a @click event (perhaps in the template v-slot activator for item.data-table-select and header.data-table-select?)

```
<v-data-table show-select ...>
```

As an example in the table shown in the link below, if I clicked the checkbox on the row that says 'cupcake' the row becomes checked. I would now like to notify other components that this has happened.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#selectable-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the :item-selected event.

Comment: This works pretty good, but it doesn't fire when someone clicks the 'select all' checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

In **vuetify 2**: the props property is no longer applicable. Therefore you have to device your own way which in my case I check whether the given item is in the array of the selected items with `array.includes(myCurrentItem)`

e.g.

```
<v-data-table
    v-model="selectedItems"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    show-select
  >
  <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
    <v-btn :disabled="selectedItems.includes(item)"
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

In **vuetify 1.5:** you could use: `item.selected` property on the item itself e.g.

```
<v-data-table
    v-model="selectedItems"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    select-all
    v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"
    item-key="name"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
  <template slot="items" scope="props">
    <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
      <td>
        <v-checkbox
          primary
          hide-details
          :input-value="props.selected"
        ></v-checkbox>
      </td>
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">
           <v-btn :disabled="!item.selected">button</v-btn>
      </td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```